# Can I configure an entity to eager load a relation using an EntityTypeConfiguration<T> object?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, eager-loading

I have table `Employer` and `EmployerParam`. Almost needless to say 1 `Employer` has 1 to many `EmployeeParams`. I want that every time an `Employee` is loaded, its `EmployeeParams` are included, i.e. eager-loaded.

The only other was I can think of is using a repository method, but that can always be bypassed and the `Employer` loaded without Params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no configuration for eager loading. You always have to call the Include method. For example in a helper method.

```
 return this.Employer.Include(e => e.EmployeeParams);
```

Comment: Yet most times Include only accepts a string and not a lambda, as in your example. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Add following namespace: using System.Data.Entity;

Comment: Which EF version are you using?

Comment: I'm using v5. It was the missing `using System.Data.Entity;`, thanks.